# How to access Salesforce tables from unix shell script?

Tags: soql, query

I have requirement to retrieve Salesforce source table counts via unix shell script. This shell script can be called in Informatica workflow as command task. Can someone please provide me with sample script?

Comment: One of the options could be REST API + curl -- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_curl.htm

Comment: Can we do authentication to get session id as per reference given in this URL: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_curl.htm? And call the SOQL query as shown in this reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_code.htm?

Comment: I'd use [`simple_salesforce`](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce) with a tiny bit of Python.